# Android Layout dynamic width

Tags: android, layout, width

Is it possible to dynamically create Layouts which be 50% width, so 3rd one to be under first one? I have tried with `android:layout_weight=".5"`, but it doesn't working.

**EDIT**: No proper answer by far

Comment: what does "so 3rd one to be on bottom of first first one" mean?

Comment: under the first one

Answer (score 0):

You can do the follwoing with a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Takes up half the width" />
</LinearLayout>
```

By setting the weightSum on the parent, you're saying that the weights of the children should equal that amount. By setting the single child's weight to half of that, it'll take up half the space. Make sure to set the width of the child to 0 so it knows to use the weight value to calculate its space relative to its parent.

Comment: not working. third layout is not under the first one

Comment: your answer is same as I said that is not working in description, but instead of weightSum 1 and weight .5 you use 2 and 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent):

add the library

compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'

[Example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html):

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: I need to use it on LinearLayout